# How to create blob from binary data in OpenVino

Tags: c++, openvino

Good day to all!

Help me please.

I have two files: model.xml and weights.bin. Function `CNNNetwork ReadNetwork(const std::string& modelPath, const std::string& binPath)` work perfectly. But i tried to get raw data from these files and call the second overload `CNNNetwork ReadNetwork(const std::string& model, const Blob::CPtr& weights)`. How can i create Blob::CPtr from raw binary data from weights.bin? I haven't found any direct methods

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have the IR files (XML and BIN), I assume your model is supported by OpenVINO.

The next step that you need to do is, use the XML file with the OpenVINO compile tool to produce a blob file.

You may import the compiled blob file to your application for further use.

Refer to this [official OpenVINO documentation](https://docs.openvino.ai/2021.4/openvino_inference_engine_tools_compile_tool_README.html?) for more detailed information.